# How to remove looading percentage spinner in Nuxtjs App

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

If you go to my website [chateg](http://chateg.com) and browse the website with slow internet connection you can see rounded spinner with percentage counter on about "Enter chat" button. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 3):

Nuxt.js uses its own component to show a progress bar between the routes. You can customize it, disable it or create your own component.

If you don't want to display the progress bar between the routes, simply add loading: false in your nuxt.config.js file:

```
 loading: false
```

for more details take a look at this link 
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-loading/

Comment: I tried it but did not work. I think this `loading` controls the line in the header cause it has properties like `color` and `height`. And when I set `loading: false` it is removing the spinner in the header.

Comment: The loading spinner seems to belons to `vue-flux` plugin. I think I am a little confused